# How do you write an iterator to a File or Stdout (anything implementing Write)?

Tags: io, iterator, rust

I have an iterator full of `u8`'s that I want to write to a file or stdout. Calling `io::stdout().write_all(foo)` on my iterator gives me an expected type `&[u8]`, and that I have an iterator type instead. I understand why this doesn't work.

What I don't understand is how to change it so that it does work. At first I tried adding a `.collect()` to the end of my iterator, but then it says `the trait bound &[u8]: std::iter::FromIterator<u8> is not satisfied` and `a collection of type &[u8] cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type u8`.

It seems odd to me that Write doesn't provide a way of writing with an iterator, when Read provides a `bytes()` function that returns an iterator. What is the idiomatic way to do this?

Here is my main function's contents:

```
io::stdout().write_all(
    io::stdin().bytes().map(
        |x| match x {
            Ok(b) => b,
            _ => panic!("There was an error reading from stdin"),
        }
    ).repeat(3).collect()
);
```

Comment: Please include the **complete error output**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems odd to me that `Write` doesn't provide a way of writing with an iterator, when `Read` provides a `bytes()` function that returns an iterator. What is the idiomatic way to do this?

It does feel inconsistent, indeed, but you can certainly write the equivalent yourself.

Something like:

```
fn write_all<W: Write, I: Iterator<Item=u8>>(writer: &mut W, iter: I) {
    const SIZE: usize = 1024;

    let mut buffer = [0u8; SIZE];
    let mut index = 0;

    for i in iter {
        buffer[index] = i;

        index += 1;
        if index == SIZE {
            writer.write_all(&buffer);
        }
    }

    writer.write_all(&buffer[..index]);
}
```

There are probably ways to make it more idiomatic, and I haven't tested the boundary conditions, but hopefully it should get you going.

Comment: io::BufWriter can be used to get rid of most of the code here

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to build a `Vec<u8>`, but are attempting to create a `Vec<&u8>`. You can do the following:

```
fn main() {
    let array = [1u8, 2, 3];
    let vector: Vec<u8> = array.iter().map(|i| *i).collect();
}
```

Note the `.map(|i| *i)` part that allows to go from `&u8` references to `u8` values.

Comment: When I add the `.map(|i| *i)`, I get `type u8 cannot be dereferenced`.

Comment: In that case can you include some of your code in the question?